MongoDB NodeJS Driver and background '$out' to S3 using mongoDB Federation
mongoDB Federation has an export feature to S3 using $out.
There is also an option 'background':true to have an immediate response and don't wait for the final result.
The query is executed using nodeJS Driver and there is no background support. Is there a way to post a command to mongoDB Federation using the background mode ?
Thanks.
